# cuda batched cholesky factorization

Tags: cuda

I kinda understand how to deal with 2D cuda. But batched cholesky has a 4D towards the end of the algorithm. I attached cholesky and my cuda code if anyone could give me a hint.

```
int i, k, m, n;
    // Batched Cholesky factorization.
    for (i = 0; i < batch; i++) {

            float *pA = &dA[i*N*N];

            // Single Cholesky factorization.
            for (k = 0; k < N; k++) {

                    // Panel factorization.
                    pA[k*N+k] = sqrtf(pA[k*N+k]);

                    for (m = k+1; m < N; m++)
                            pA[k*N+m] /= pA[k*N+k];

                    // Update of the trailing submatrix.
                    for (n = k+1; n < N; n++)
                            for (m = n; m < N; m++)
                                    pA[n*N+m] -= (pA[k*N+n]*pA[k*N+m]);
            }


    }
```

Cuda:

```
    int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int k = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int m = blockIdx.z * blockDim.z + threadIdx.z;
    int n = blockIdx.z * blockDim.z + threadIdx.z;

    if( k >= N || m >= N || n >= N || i >= batch ) return;
    float *pA = &dA[i*N*N];
    pA[k*N+k] = sqrtf(pA[k*N+k]);
    pA[k*N+m] /= pA[k*N+k];
    pA[n*N+m] -= (pA[k*N+n]*pA[k*N+m]);
```

starter:

```
    dim3 dimBlock( (batch+31)/32, (n+31)/32, (n+31)/32 );
    dim3 dimGrid( 32, 32, 32);

    spotrf_batched_kernel<<< dimBlock, dimGrid, 0, stream>>>(n, batch, dA);
```

Comment: If you want a hint -- you have to understand how the algorithm works before trying to parallelize it. There is necessary ordering in this type of block Cholesky factorization which your approach would break, Study the serial code carefully and then try again

Comment: All Im doing is looking at this for loop and translate into Cuda code. If everything looks fine, serialize would mean to add __syncthreads() right?

Comment: Also all the examples I found, the counters all start with 0. In this case, the inner loop starts with k+1. Do I need to change m and n in this case?

Comment: The entire point is that you *can't* just "look at loops and translate them". In CUDA there is no guaranteed execution order at all. You cannot run that algorithm ad hoc and expect it to work. It requires that each row occurs in the correct sequence, and that the panel factorization for a given row is finished before the update propagation for that row

Comment: So I should just add syncthreads in between and expect it to work? I think I'm missing more on how to manage threads and blocks

Comment: No that won't work  it is only a intra-block level barrier. What you are missing is an understanding of the algorithm you are trying to parallelize and how CUDA fundamentally works. Without those two things you are wasting your time

Comment: I do have a little understanding of cuda but not cholesky. I did get it to work with multiple blocks and one thread for each block. But if I add in threads everything falls apart.

Comment: So basically what you are saying is that when you run the algorithm with one thread per batch (i.e. serially) it works correctly. Sound familiar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to leave this here without much comment. The code is relatively self-explanatory. This implementation is completely faithful to your serial version, with the following features:

1. Each block performs exactly one factorization in the batch. Run as many blocks as there are batched matrices to factorize.
2. Because the factorization is all done at block scope, synchronization between parallel operations is possible, so the order of operations of the factorization is respected
3. The only parallelism the algorithm exposes is within the row operations of the factorization and update operations
4. Blocks should be sized according to the number of rows in the batch matrix size in round multiples of the warp size (32 on all CUDA capable devices to date)

The code below has been extremely lightly tested and is not guaranteed to work or be correct. Use at your own peril:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

__global__ 
void batchkernel(float** batches, int nbatches, int N, int LDA)
{
    if (blockIdx.x < nbatches) {
        float* pA = batches[blockIdx.x];
        for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) {

            // Panel factorization.
            if (threadIdx.x == 0)  {
                pA[k*LDA+k] = sqrtf(pA[k*LDA+k]);
            }
            __syncthreads();

            for (int m = threadIdx.x; ((m < N) && (threadIdx.x > k)); m+=blockDim.x) {
                pA[k*LDA+m] /= pA[k*LDA+k];
            }
            __syncthreads();

            // Update of the trailing submatrix.
            for (int n = k+1; (n < N); n++) {
                for (int m = threadIdx.x; ((m < N) && (threadIdx.x >= n)); m+=blockDim.x) {
                    pA[n*LDA+m] -= pA[k*LDA+n] * pA[k*LDA+m];
                }
            }
            __syncthreads();
        }
    }
}

void refCholeskey(float* pA, int N)
{
    int k, m, n;

    // Single Cholesky factorization.
    for (k = 0; k < N; k++) {
        // Panel factorization.
        pA[k*N+k] = sqrtf(pA[k*N+k]);

        for (m = k+1; m < N; m++)
            pA[k*N+m] /= pA[k*N+k];

        // Update of the trailing submatrix.
        for (n = k+1; n < N; n++)
            for (m = n; m < N; m++)
                pA[n*N+m] -= (pA[k*N+n]*pA[k*N+m]);
    }
}


int main()
{
    // B = np.random.random((10,10))
    // SPDmatrix = (0.5*(B+B.T)) + B.shape[0]*np.eye(B.shape[0])
    const int N = 10;
    const int LDA = 10;
    float SPDmatrix[LDA*N] = {
    10.22856331,   0.17380577,   0.61779525,   0.66592082,   0.46915566,
     0.09946502,   0.69386511,   0.35224291,   0.53155506,   0.51441469,
     0.17380577,  10.67971161,   0.34481401,   0.64766522,   0.22372943,
     0.55896022,   0.59083588,   0.48872497,   0.54049871,   0.74764959,
     0.61779525,   0.34481401,    10.229388,   0.40904432,    0.5015491,
     0.52152334,   0.19684814,   0.28262256,   0.04384535,   0.61919751,
     0.66592082,   0.64766522,   0.40904432,  10.78410647,   0.12708693,
      0.3241063,    0.6984497,   0.65074097,   0.08027563,   0.56332844,
     0.46915566,   0.22372943,    0.5015491,   0.12708693,  10.52234091,
     0.76346103,   0.80932473,    0.8234331,   0.52737611,   0.65777357,
     0.09946502,   0.55896022,   0.52152334,    0.3241063,   0.76346103,
    10.54906761,   0.32865411,   0.32467483,   0.80720007,   0.36287463,
     0.69386511,   0.59083588,   0.19684814,    0.6984497,   0.80932473,
     0.32865411,  10.29729551,   0.34707933,   0.69379356,   0.87612982,
     0.35224291,   0.48872497,   0.28262256,   0.65074097,    0.8234331,
     0.32467483,   0.34707933,  10.42929929,   0.78849458,     0.159371,  
     0.53155506,   0.54049871,   0.04384535,   0.08027563,   0.52737611,
     0.80720007,   0.69379356,   0.78849458,  10.49604818,   0.43871288,
     0.51441469,   0.74764959,   0.61919751,   0.56332844,   0.65777357,
     0.36287463,   0.87612982,     0.159371,   0.43871288,  10.94535485 };

    const int nbatches = 8;
    float** batches;
    cudaMallocManaged((void **)&batches, nbatches * sizeof(float*));

    for(int i=0; i<nbatches; i++) {
        cudaMallocManaged((void **)&batches[i], N * LDA * sizeof(float));
        cudaMemcpy(batches[i], SPDmatrix, N * LDA * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDefault);
    }

    int blocksz = 32;
    int nblocks = nbatches;

    batchkernel<<<nblocks, blocksz>>>(batches, nbatches, N, LDA);
    refCholeskey(SPDmatrix, N);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    float maxabsrelerror = 0.0f;
    for(int i = 0; i < N*N; i++) {
        float absrelerror = std::fabs(SPDmatrix[i] - batches[0][i]) / std::fabs(SPDmatrix[i]);
        maxabsrelerror = std::max(absrelerror, maxabsrelerror);
    }
    std::cout << "Maximum absolute relative error = " << maxabsrelerror << std::endl;

    cudaDeviceReset();

    return 0;
}
```